# How do you refer to a VueJS component's name within the template's raw HTML / x-referenced ID element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm essentially trying to add a CSS class to my VueJS components based on the `component-name` it's registered under (to give all those specific types of components the same style).

For example:

```
Vue.component('dragdropfile', {
    // This refers to a unique template element (see HTML below)
    template: "#dragdropfile-tmp",
    props: ['action']
});
```

And in the Vue component template:

```
<template id="dragdropfile-tmp">
    <form action="{{action}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
        </div>
        <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
            <div class="dz-default">
                <!--
                    According to VueJS docs / forums, "slot" gets replaced by any innerHTML
                    passed from the incoming component usage.
                -->
                <slot></slot> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

And finally, how it's used in the "index.html" page is like this:

```
<dragdropfile id="someDragDropFiles" action="/upload-please">
  Do you have files to upload?<br/>
  <b>Drop it here!</b>
</dragdropfile>
```

Now, although I could put in the component-name manually for each component HTML templates, I want to automate this.

Are there any special built-in `{{binding}}` names that Vue uses internally so that I can inject the component-name into the resulting component on the page?

To result something like so:

> <form class="**dragdropfile**" id="someDragDropFiles" action="/upload-please" ... >
>  ...
> </form>

Or do I simply need to pass it myself as a new component property? As in:

- Manually call it like `props: ["componentName", ...]` and;
- Refer to it in the template as `<form class='{{componentName}}' ...>`

Is this the only feasible way?

## Using VueJS version: 1.0.17

(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.17/vue.js)

Comment: Note that a solution doesn't necessarily have to work with `v1.0.17`, I could upgrade to the latest as of today (`v2.1.6`) if it has some better handling for this particular case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Solution #1

After a few minutes of inspecting what the object holds using the `create: function() { console.log(this); }` in the `Vue.component(...)` registration call, I found the name in it's `this.$options.name` property.

In other words:

> <form class="**{{this.$options.name}}**" ...> ... </form>

Or even shorter:

> <form class="**{{$options.name}}**" ...> ... </form>

Come to think of it, it's still a bit of manual work to enter on each component templates, but there's probably a way to auto-append the class via the `created` method.

---

## Solution #2

This is the automated approach I was looking for!

Here it goes, basically I made a wrapper function to call whenever I need to register new components, which internally calls the usual `Vue.component(...)` method.

> **NOTE:** This example depends on **jQuery** to add the class and **underscore.js** for object merging via `_.assign`, but could probably be replaced by a direct `*.classList.addClass()` call instead. These are just the helper methods I'm familiar with, use what you like! :)

### makeVueComponent(name, params)

```
/*
 * Creates a Vue Component with a standardized template ID name (ie: #tagname-tmp)
 * combined with given params.
 */
function makeVueComponent(name, params) {
    //Ensure params is assigned something:
    params = params || {};

    //Backup a reference of an existing *.created() method, or just an empty function
    var onCreated = params.created || function(){};

    /*
        Delete the original `created` method so the `_.assign()` call near the end
        doesn't accidentally merge and overwrite our defaultParams.created() method.
     */
    delete params.created; 

    var defaultParams = {
        //Standardized template components to expect a '-tmp' suffix
        // (this gets auto-generated by my NodeJS/Express routing)
        template: "#"+name+"-tmp",

        // This part auto-adds a class name matching the registered component-name
        created: function() {
            var $el = $(this.$options.el);
            $el.addClass(this.$options.name);

            //Then forward this to any potential custom 'created' methods we had in 'params':
            onCreated.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };

    //Merge default params with given custom params:
    params = _.assign(defaultParams, params);

    Vue.component(name, params);
}
```

And then just use it like so:

```
//Register your Vue Components:
makeVueComponent("dragdropfile", {props:['action']});
```

You can then leave out those `{{$options.name}}` from your actual component templates that I mentioned in **Solution 1**.